# How can I make NetBeans fetch the Java SE documentation from src.zip?

Tags: java, netbeans

By default, NetBeans fetches the Java SE 8 documentation from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/. I'd like it to fetch it from the src.zip instead, so it doesn't unnecessarily cause a delay by connecting to the internet ("Downloading HTTP javadoc").

When I remove the entry in Tools > Java Platforms > Javadoc, it works as expected. But this only lasts until the next start of NetBeans, because then the entry is back.

Comment: I don't think NetBeans can display the JavaDocs from the sources. You will need to store them locally and then add _that_ directory to the JDK definition in NetBeans.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It can. If it fails to load the docs from the URL it falls back to the javadoc comments in src.zip.